# Cannot I do a getResources.getString dynamically?

Tags: android, string, getresource, getstring

I'm trying to fill a `Spinner` with the values of some `Strings` of `string.xml`. I'm trying to do like that:

```
   final List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
   for (int i = 0; i < 86; i++) {
      String resource = "R.string." + ntpServers[i][0];
      list.add(getResources().getString(resource));
   }
```

I have strings like the next ones.

```
<string name="AT">Austria</string>
<string name="BY">Belarus</string>
<string name="BE">Belgium</string>
```

And **from a Geocoder** I get a country code like AT, BY, etc. Which are stored in the ntpServers array. I want to fill the spinner with the name saved in the correspondent string, but I cannot do `getResources().getString(resource)` because `resource` is a `String` not an `int`.

How can I solve this?

Thanks for your advices.

P.D.:

I get the next sequence:

For Example:

```
geocoder.getCountry() = ES --> ntpServers[36][0] = ES --> R.string.ES = """Spain"""
```

Which is the string that I want in the spinner.

***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_***

This is what I'm trying to do now. I'm using **getIdentifier**.

```
final List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < 86; i++) {
   String resource = "R.string." + ntpServers[i][0];
   Log.i("RESOURCE", resource);
   Log.i("getResource", "" + getResources().getIdentifier(resource, "string", getPackageName()));
                list.add(getResources().getString(getResources().getIdentifier(resource, "string", getPackageName())));
}
```

And this is the log cat

```
09-18 19:32:43.815: I/RESOURCE(31268): R.string.Global
09-18 19:32:43.815: I/getResource(31268): 0
09-18 19:32:43.815: W/ResourceType(31268): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
09-18 19:32:43.815: D/AndroidRuntime(31268): Shutting down VM
09-18 19:32:43.815: W/dalvikvm(31268): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40fa92a0)
09-18 19:32:43.815: E/AndroidRuntime(31268): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-18 19:32:43.815: E/AndroidRuntime(31268): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
09-18 19:32:43.815: E/AndroidRuntime(31268):    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java)
09-18 19:32:43.815: E/AndroidRuntime(31268):    at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java)
09-18 19:32:43.815: E/AndroidRuntime(31268):    at victor.martin.gplace.MainActivity$3.run(MainActivity.java:790)
09-18 19:32:43.815: E/AndroidRuntime(31268):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java)
09-18 19:32:43.815: E/AndroidRuntime(31268):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
09-18 19:32:43.815: E/AndroidRuntime(31268):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
09-18 19:32:43.815: E/AndroidRuntime(31268):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
09-18 19:32:43.815: E/AndroidRuntime(31268):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-18 19:32:43.815: E/AndroidRuntime(31268):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
09-18 19:32:43.815: E/AndroidRuntime(31268):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
09-18 19:32:43.815: E/AndroidRuntime(31268):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
09-18 19:32:43.815: E/AndroidRuntime(31268):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And this is the R.java:

```
public static final class string {
        public static final int AE=0x7f080049;
        public static final int AO=0x7f08005b;
        ...
        public static final int Global=0x7f080008;
```

Let's see if you can guide me more.

Eternal Thanks ^^

Comment: Take a look at String Array http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray in the documentation, that looks more like what you want

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @Henry advised me, I have used getIdentifier with the next code:

```
list.add(getResources().getString(getResources().getIdentifier(ntpServers[i][0], "string", getPackageName())));
```

The problem was that the resource name that we need to find didn't needed the prefix "R.string", only the name.

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 9):

Use string-array like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="item">
        <item>AT</item>
        <item>BY</item>
        <item>BE</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>


Resources res = getResources();
String[] array = res.getStringArray(R.array.item);
```

convert Array to List

```
List list = Arrays.asList(array);
```

/* According to your requirement */
In order to solve your issue use HashMap which keep data in the form of key value pair.

```
public HashMap<String, String> getCountryCode() {
        HashMap<String, String> countryCode = new HashMap<String, String>();
        countryCode.put("IN", "INDIA");
        countryCode.put("ES", "Spain");
        countryCode.put("USA", "United States of America");

        return countryCode;
    }

String countryName= getCountryCode().get(geocoder.getCountry());
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: This is not exactly what I'm searching but it's a good solution. Thanks.

Comment: @Victor_J_Martin I edited my answer. Hope this will work for you.

Comment: I didn't know the existence of HashMap. But the idea of use R.string is for a multilingual purposes. I can do the same thing with HashMap?? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `Resources.getIdentifier` method ([see here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)) which converts a resource name to the int resource identifier. However, this is slower than using an array.

Comment: I added some info when I have try to use getIdentifier

Comment: @Victor_J_Martin the resource name should not have the "R.string" prefix included. In the example just use "Global".

Comment: Thanks @Henry it was failing for the prefix "R.string" ;) Thank you so much. 

This is the correct form:

list.add(getResources().getString(getResources().getIdentifier(ntpServers[i][0], "string", getPackageName())));

Comment: I have retaken this project to update the version. But formerly, I used Eclipse IDE, and now I use Android Studio. Now the list.add(...) is marked as error by Android Studio saying me that "Expected resource of type string". I don't know what is the problem. If you can help me, I would be grateful.

Comment: Make it a new question, more detail is needed to identify the problem.

Comment: Thank, at this moment, It compiles and runs, although the error is there. If later makes me more problems, I will post it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

array in strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="items">
        <item>Austria</item>
        <item>Belarus</item>
        <item>Belgium</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

To populate spinner

```
Spinner sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(ActivityName.this, R.array.item, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
sp.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another similar solution but it use the *`Collections`* helper class:

**strings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="countries">
        <item>Austria</item>
        <item>Belarus</item>
        <item>Belgium</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

-

```
    String[] countryNames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries);
    List<String> countryList = new ArrayList<String>();

    Collections.addAll(countryList, countryNames);
```